# Как получить значение из другого потока по клику?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Есть событие клика:

```
  const click$ = fromEvent(this.image.nativeElement, 'click');
```

И событие включения кнопки:

```
const btnClick$ = fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click');
```

Как по клику click$ - получать значение из `btnClick$` и `click$`?

Пробовал так - срабатывает один раз немотря на то что продолжаю делать клик:

```
click$
  .pipe(switchMap(() => btnClick$))
  .subscribe(r => console.log('Saved!', r));
```

Answer (score 1):

[Реализация](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-u1qe8k?file=src/app/app.component.ts):

```
...
 ngOnInit() {
      this.click$ = fromEvent(this.image.nativeElement, 'click');
      this.btnClick$ = fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click');


     this.click$
     .pipe(
        scan(currentState => !currentState, false),
        switchMap(res => res ? this.btnClick$ : empty())
       )
      .subscribe(r => console.log(r));
   }
```

Логика работы:
задаем начальное состояние картинки  scan(currentState => !currentState, **false**),
далее отрабатывает переключение состояни scan(**currentState => !currentState**, false).
При `currentState = true` отслеживаем кнопку, при состоянии false выполняем `empty`